# Generalized Issue on WSH.Run CMD Type Code

Tags: vba, excel, cmd

The following is NOT my code. I am constantly tripping the error code within the text. I was told the following to implement the code:

You must set a reference to `Windows Script Host Object Model`. `sDrive` and `sBasePath` are used to set the starting folder name. `sFileList` is where the results will be written into a text file.

I have set `Windows Script Host Object Model` to be referenced, but still I cannot get it to run successfully without tripping the built in error. Please help

```
Public sDrive As String
Public sBasePath As String
Public Const sFileList As String = "U:\"
Option Explicit
Sub GetDirTree()
    Dim WSH As WshShell
    Dim lErrCode As Long

    Set WSH = New WshShell
    lErrCode = WSH.Run("cmd.exe /c dir """ & sDrive & sBasePath & """/B /S >" & sFileList, 0, True)
    If lErrCode <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Error in GetDirTree: Error Number: " & CStr(lErrCode))
        Stop
    End If

End Sub
```

Code Credit to: [Ron Rosenfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2872922/ron-rosenfeld)

Comment: It seems that `sDrive` and `sBasePath` should be assigned some string values before being stuffed into a command. Similarly, `sFileList` should be a fllename to receive the output, not a drive root folder.

Comment: Aha. I am going to look into this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The following code requires that the **Windows Script Host Object Model** be added to the project via the VBE's Tools ► Referenced command.

You have missed the assignment of some variables; e.g. they are vbnullstrings when declared and not assigned values.

```
Option Explicit

Public sDrive As String
Public sBasePath As String
Public sFileList As String

Sub GetDirTree()
    Dim WSH As WshShell
    Dim lErrCode As Long

    sDrive = "c:\"
    sBasePath = "New Folder\*"
    sFileList = Environ("TEMP") & Chr(92) & "My_Dir_List.txt"
    Debug.Print "cmd.exe /c dir """ & sDrive & sBasePath & """/B /S >" & sFileList

    Set WSH = New WshShell
    lErrCode = WSH.Run("cmd.exe /c dir """ & sDrive & sBasePath & """/B /S >" & sFileList, 0, True)
    If lErrCode <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Error in GetDirTree: Error Number: " & CStr(lErrCode))
        Stop
    End If

End Sub
```

I've changed the declaration of `sFileList` to make it public but not const. You cannot change a **const**ant variable on-the-fly. The `sFileList` will be put into the folder designated by the TEMP environment variable. This is handy as there should be no write permission error. I've sent the command to be used to the VBE's Immediate window for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much Jeeped!